# How to get href link using a CSS selector

Tags: python, web-scraping, css-selectors

So i'm building a scrapy web crawler, and i want to extract the link within the `href`.

```
<li class="next">
<a class="button-text link-next" tabindex="0" role="button" href="drugs-all-medicines?page=2">Next &gt;</a></li>
```

but when i use the code given below in shell, it only gives me output before the`?`

```
In [6]: response.css('li.next a ::attr(href)').get()
Out[6]: 'drugs-all-medicines'
```

i want to get the whole link like this -`drugs-all-medicines?page=2`

So this is the whole code-block i'm using :

```
    import scrapy
import re

class MedspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "medspider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.1mg.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.1mg.com/drugs-all-medicines"]

    def parse(self, response):
        meds = response.css('div.style__flex-1___A_qoj'),
        element = response.css('li.next a ::attr(href)').get(),
        link = re.findall('href="(.*?)"', element)[0],
        print(link),
        for med in meds:
            yield{
                'name' : med.css('div div::text').get(),
                'price' : med.css('div:has(> span)::text').getall()[-1],
                'strip content' :  med.css('div::text').getall()[-4],
                'manufacturer' :  med.css('div::text').getall()[-3],
            }
```

Comment: What version of Scrapy are you using? This works fine for me.

Comment: its the latest one

Comment: What numerical version is that for you? Also, which website are you scraping?

Comment: its scrapy 2.9.0 and im scraping https://www.1mg.com/drugs-all-medicines

Comment: Can i use '.re' anyhow?

Comment: I'm guessing it found an earlier element on the page, that actually did have an href of just  `drugs-all-medicines`.

Comment: Yeah there is but the 'li' class name is different in that tag

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the `::attr(href)` psuedo-element, you could get select `li.next a` to get the text of the `<a>` element, then use a regular expression to get all the text inside the quotes that follow `href=`. Here's some code:

```
import re

element = response.css('li.next a').get()
link = re.findall('href="(.*?)"', element)[0]

print(link)  # => drugs-all-medicines?page=2
```

Comment: you can check out the code i'm using, and i'm still not getting output using your code. i know the mistakes are on my side, so can you just help me out